# Varying Length (Timesteps) Sequences for PyTorch LSTM Training

Tags: pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataset with shape (1000,1440,2) which is (samples,timesteps,features) as a np array. Each sample has its own number of timestep, so to create this dataset, I have padded the samples with a neutral value (-9999). Coming from TensorFlow, I used a Keras Masking layer to skip these padded values. Now, I have to switch to PyTorch and I don’t know how I should do this in PyTorch. Searching the net just made more confused on what to do.

Greatly appreciate your help in advance! not sure how to approach this.